# How exclude column from mongo query result for java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have such mongodb query:

```
db.getCollection("author").find({}, {_id: 0})
```

How can I write it with java? Now I can only make a query on all columns, but I would like to understand how to remove a specific column from the result. For example, _id.

My java query now:

```java
FindIterable<Document> documents = authorCollection.find();
```

*I will be grateful for your advices!*

Answer (score 0):

To solve the question I need to use `projection()` with `excludeId()`:

```
authorCollection.find().projection(excludeId());
```